# Do you know the equivalent of the Intel Pin utility for AMD processors

Tags: instrumentation

Do you know an instrument equivalent to Intel Pin (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) for AMD processors, which helps me especially for reverse of whitebox (https://insinuator.net/2016/03/how-to-crack-a-white-box-without-much-effort/).

Comment: There's DynamoRIO but AFAIK Intel Pin should also work on AMD processors otherwise it's a shame given the popularity of the Zen 2 chips these days.

Comment: I have a ryzen 2700X and pintool works fine on it.